# Changing badge number daily

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am looking for a medhold to add 1 for each day to the badge icon. I have tried multiple ways, but none of them have updated the icon badge number.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
    localNotification.alertBody = nil;
    localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

    //Add one to the icon badge number

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1;


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: How about a timer that lasts 24hrs and sends a notification each time it fires? The badge should automatically increase by 1 each time and maybe you can disable the banner if you want to

Comment: @LinusG. How would you implement the timer? Could you show me the code ?

Answer (score 0):

So I would choose another approach. My idea is to set a self-repeating timer that fires every 86,400s (24hrs/1d) and sends a notification. If that works the badge count would increase automatically by one.

```
//!pseudo-code!
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(864000, target: self, selector: "sendNotification:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func sendNotification(timer: NSTimer) {
    //initialize and send your notification w/ repeatCount: 0 and fireDate: now
    //hide the banner so the user does not visually see the notification if you wish
}
```

I am not sure whether this will work if the app is not running but it may be worth a try.